# Selecting an item from the dropdown list but refreshes the page

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am doing an automated testing for a website with a dropdown with list of item. I am trying to select an item from the dropdown. The following code selects the item I am trying to select but then the page refreshes and the dropdown box reverts to the original option and looses the option selected by the following code.

```
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#_attend_status_0'))-> click();
echo "Mark roll status dropdown accessed... \n";

$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('ATTEND_STATUS3'))->click(); 
echo " Absent Status Selected \n";
```

Following is the html source code

```
<select class="_attend_status_select" name="_attend_status_0" id="_attend_status_0" onchange="filterStatusChange(this.value, '_time_input_0', 908, 99 );
                                                     resetCheckbox(this.value, 0); " onkeyup="checkKeycode(event, 0, this.value, '_time_input_0', 908, 99, 7, '2'); " tabindex="6"><option id="ATTEND_STATUS1" value="1">None</option>
<option id="ATTEND_STATUS3" value="3">Absent</option>
<option id="ATTEND_STATUS4" value="4">Late</option>
<option id="ATTEND_STATUS5" value="5">Late Signed In</option>
<option id="ATTEND_STATUS18" value="18">Music</option>
<option id="ATTEND_STATUS19" value="19">Other Activity</option>
<option id="ATTEND_STATUS20" value="20">Pastoral Care</option>
<option id="ATTEND_STATUS2" value="2">Present</option></select>
```

Comment: Please show the full code

Comment: for a dropdown list u can use send_keys also

Comment: i have added the html source code as an instance

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments I have solved the problem. It was the refresh function that I used in the beginning that was trigerring the refresh every 20 sec.